# Create a table from a query in access VBA

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vba

I have this query that I created in VBA and I want to make it into a table within VBA.  Is there anyway I could do this? I have looked into a make table query but I am unsure how to create one inside VBA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub RevH()
Dim dte As String, clientQry As String, db As Database, clientQry1 As Variant


Set db = CurrentDb


dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")


clientQry = "SELECT DISTINCT t.[CLIENT ID], t.[CLIENT NAME] " & _
            "FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte & " as t WHERE " & _
            " (((t.[CLIENT NAME]) Not Like  ""*Test*"" ));"

If CheckQuery("NewIDs") = "Yes" Then
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "NewIDs"
End If


clientQry1 = db.CreateQueryDef("NewIDs", clientQry)




End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you want to make a new query for that? Simply execute the SQL by invoking the CurrentDb.Execute method.

And second: the correct syntax for a query that create a new table would be:

```
SELECT YourFields INTO YourNewTable FROM YourOldTable
```

so simply make something like that:

```
Dim clientQry as String

clientQry = "SELECT DISTINCT t.[CLIENT ID], t.[CLIENT NAME] " & _
            "INTO NewTableName " & _
            "FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte & " as t WHERE " & _
            " (((t.[CLIENT NAME]) Not Like  ""*Test*"" ));"

CurrentDb.Execute clientQry, dbFailOnError
```

by the way: most time it's a bad idea to make physical copies of a table. Normally you would setup ONE history table with an additional date column and dump all copies into that table. During runtime it should NEVER be requiered to add new tables / columns. Anything else is an indication of a bad data model!